# How to set IDENTITY_INSERT on or off at runtime using Linq-to-SQL in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

How to turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` on or off at runtime using Linq-to-SQL in VB.NET?

I want to insert new rows using specific id, but the `id` column of my table is an identity column.

So I want to turn on `IDENTITY_INSERT` before inserting the row, and turn it back off after the insert.

I used Linq-to-SQL, is their is any way to achieve this using vb.net?

Comment: I don't think Linq-to-SQL has any specific means for doing this - so you basically just need to do it yourself, using the `DataContext.ExecuteCommand` method.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/566e9540-911e-48b4-ac31-f69c0ab9f7fb/) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1208607.aspx).